# Capital gain tax from closing down the company in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gain, form-1040, schedule-d

I need help with filing form line 6 form 1040. we live in uk.

my husband work as contractor for short term and he need to get pay through his own company.
after few months it didnt work out and become employee again and had to close the company

He had capital gain of small amount and we do not need to pay tax in uk as it is under threshold.
it was reported as capital gain in form 1040 line 6.

do we need schedule D or any other form  ??

thanks

Comment: Where did the capital gains come from? Is that the only US income you will have?

Comment: the capital gain come from retained earning when company closed down.

Comment: this is income from UK

Comment: no other US income. thanks

Comment: On the 2021 1040 tax from line 6 is Social security benefits  Do you mean line 7?

Comment: sorry it was for 2019

Comment: we have some emloyment income in UK 2019 but did put it as the foreign income exclusion